# Checking if an integer has increased C++

Tags: c++

so not too tough I just want to understand if the following is the most efficient/fast way of checking this;

```
if (misses++)
    run_code();
```

(Basically if misses increased, run some code, useful for logging missed angles etc.)

P.S will this code run every time misses increases? Thanks :)

**EDIT**

This does not check if it increased, anybody got any ideas?

Comment: This does not mean "if `misses` increased". It means "if `misses` is not `0` and then increment `misses`".

Comment: It will be executed each time `missed` will not be equals to zero before incrementing it.

Comment: It isn't efficient because it doesn't to the thing you want it to do. As for speed, that is irrelevant if it doesn't work.

Comment: increases since when?

Comment: Alright, thanks very much still learning, how can I check if it increased? @nwp

Comment: You'll need to keep track of its last value and then check if the value has increased since then. Or instead of ever incrementing misses, just call `run_code` if you want to call it whenever the value increases

Comment: and `if (misses)` means `misses` didnt not increase? Interesting language that you are making up ;). Suggested reading: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: Shouldn't it simply be `if (++misses)`?

Comment: @BrunoCorrêaZimmermann That expression might or might not evaluate to `false` implicitly. The OP's logic is flawed to begin with.

Comment: I don't understand what the op is trying to achieve

Comment: The best place to perform your action is the location where you increment `misses`.

Answer (score 1):

**try like this:**

```
int b=misses
misses++;
if(misses>b)
{
   run_code();
   b=misses;
}
```

Comment: This if doesn't do anything, the compiler will just remove it.

Answer (score 1):

To determine whether a value has increased you have to make a note of the original value, so that you can compare:

```
void f(int& arg); // might change arg

int main() {
    int misses = 0;
    int old_misses;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        old_misses = misses;
        f(misses);
        if (misses != old_misses)
            run_code();
    }
    return 0;
}
```